# Bazel release specific documentation

Tags: bazel

Is there any place that has the documentation for a specific bazel release? In particular the documentation at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-overview.html is not appropriate because it is updated with master and thus may not be consistent with the version of bazel that I am running. The url structure looks like it would support more than one version (replacing `master`) but the obvious replacement of `0.5.2` or `release` doesn't work.

The use case I have is reporting documentation inconsistencies with the actual code so I need documentation that is intended to be consistent, and not documenting yet unreleased features. (e.g. https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3016)

Comment: I think there are plans for version specific documentation, but it's not there yet.

Comment: There is an open issue for this: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/579

Comment: Here you can select [version](https://bazel.build/versions) from top dropdown in the documentation